# How can I cast an Object in an equals override method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, casting

I have the following code in a class used to simulate the IRS with employer filings in accordance with the filer. I am required to override the equals class but I keep getting the error saying that the methods I am trying to use cannot be found when called on the casted Object.

```
    @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if ((this == null )|| (obj == null) || (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()))
        return false;
    if ((this.sameEmployer((Employer)obj))
    && (this.getEmployeeSSN() == (Employer)obj.getEmployeeSSN())
    && (this.getName() == (Employer)obj.getName())
    && (this.getEmployeeName() == (Employer)obj.getEmployeeName())
    && (this.getEmployeeWages() == (Employer)obj.getEmployeeWages()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: One note is 'this == null' never happen so you can remove this

Comment: `this.getName() == (Employer)obj.getName()` I guess `getName()` returns a `String`, right? Then use `this.getName().equals(((Employer)obj).getName())` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Casting happens after method calls.  [According to the precedence of operators](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/), `()` for method calling is at the highest level, 1, while `()` for casting is at level 3.  In other words you are attempting to cast `obj.getEmployeeSSN()` as an `Employer`, not `obj`.

Once you know `obj` is an `Employer`, you can place parentheses to force casting first, e.g.

```
&& (this.getEmployeeSSN() == ((Employer) obj).getEmployeeSSN())
```

However, it looks like a mess of parentheses.  For clarity, just declare an `Employer` variable, cast it once, then call the methods, passing the `Employer` variable.

```
Employer emp = (Employer) obj;
if (this.sameEmployer(emp)
    && ...
```

Answer (score 2):

For expressions like this:

```
(Employer)obj.getEmployeeSSN()
```

The `.` has higher precedence - "binds tighter" - than the cast. So it's closer to:

```
(Employer) (obj.getEmployeeSSN())
```

... whereas you want:

```
((Employer) obj).getEmployeeSSN()
```

in order to cast and *then* call the method. That's most easily done by casting in an earlier line:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    // Now use "other" in the rest of the code:
    return sameEmployer(other)
        && getEmployeeSSN() == other.getEmployeeSSN()
        ...;
}
```

Note that:

- `this` can never be null, so you don't need to test it
- You don't need nearly as many brackets as you had before
- I'd strongly encourage you to use braces for all `if` blocks... you'd be surprised at how easy it is to end up with mistakes otherwise. (There are lots of SO questions which are basically due to that...)
- Any time you have:

  ```
  if (foo) {
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
  ```

  you should simplify it to:

  ```
  return foo;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Class `Object` doesn't have `getEmployeeSSN()`. What you should have instead is :

```
(this.getEmployeeSSN() == ((Employer)obj).getEmployeeSSN() //and so forth.
```

The cast should happen first, then you try to use the method on the casted object

Comment: Well the Object must be Employer class because of the check in the first if so it would have access to the method I would have thought. So this is what I need to fix.

Comment: @Ethan, the object is an employer class, but you need to complete the cast with `(Employer)obj`, before you can use the Employer class methods.

Answer (score 0):

You just have a problem with priority of your operations. The cast to (Employer) will happen after you call the specific methods. To enforce the priority you need to add brackets:

```
((Employer) obj).getName()
```

instead of

```
(Employer) obj.getName()
```